# Subir una imagen a través de un formulario y que se muestre en el GridView

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en ASP.NET y SQLServer. Todo funciona bien, lo que quiero es

Poder subir una imagen

Guardar el nombre o ruta de la imagen en la base de datos

Mostrar la imagen en un GridView

Con este código lleno mi GridView1 en la clase Datos:

```
public class Datos
{
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadena_tres"].ToString());
//LISTAR
    public DataTable Listar()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("listar", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}

private void llenargrid()
    {
        Datos dat = new Datos();
        GridView1.DataSource = dat.Listar();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Este es el formulario que utilizo para insertar los datos, y al lado el GridView donde se muestran.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el FileUpload quiero que se puedan subir imágenes y que se guarden en la base de datos y también que se puedan mostrar en el campo Imagen del GridView.

No consigo hacerlo.

Comment: Hola JiMel, por favor para que te podamos ayudar, subi estructura de la tabla, codigo que tenes hasta el momento, que intentas hacer, te da error? Cual? Etc, de otro modo nadie va a poder darte una mano. Las preguntas tienen que tener un formato y orden, podes verificarlo en este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: tienes Asp net o mvc asp net

Comment: Estoy utilizando asp.net , empty